# open VSCode directly to remote code and folder, on macbook

Tags: visual-studio-code

Everytime I open the VSCode in Macbook I need to connect, through SSH, to the remote host on Linux, and navigate to the project folder.

There is a way to, when open VSCode to start in remote mode directly in the project folder?